# How to autoplay video without sound like Facebook & Instagram in Android webview?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

So Facebook & Instagram has a feature whereby it allows users to scroll and watch videos that are autoplayed but sound muted unless the user clicks the video.
How can I implement this feature in my android webview?

The code

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Allows the autoplay feature but how can I enable or disable the sound? Is it similar to the userGesture code?

Answer (score 0):

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Yep. I'll edit my answer. I was on transit but felt it deserves a quick answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that Setting it as "True" means the user has to click on the video for it to load.....but how can I mute the video while it plays automatically?